# How to debug prints from multiple threads/intr

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I  was trying to debug by putting prints in multiple interrupts(software).I see those prints overlapping from both the threads.

I wanted to print the some time/ticks to make sure that the both the threads are running simultaneously.

I used jiffies, But i was not getting proper change in the time. I see the same tick for multiple interrupts.

Comment: or you can use the thread id to distinguish, if you want that.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, you can use `pthread_self();` to grab the threadID. It's one of the best ways to differentiate between threads

Comment: @kwierman threadID is opaque. while you can compare 2 threadIDs with the `pthread_equal()` function it can't really be used in a print to differentiate threads.

Comment: what is it what you want to do? measure time or do you just want to know whether your threads run at the same time?

Comment: @rowan.G `printf ("%lu", pthread_self ());` ought to work on Linux, and it can really be used in debugging (and the compiler should yell at you when it is wrong format specifier).

Comment: I want to differentiate two software interrupts. Is there a way to print interrupt number

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged linux, so I'm going to give you a linux non-portable answer, because to my knowledge there is not a truly portable way to do this:

- You can use `pthread_self()`, and print that. It's an opaque type, but you can cast it to a `void *` and that works on Linux provided *your only purpose is to differentiate between threads* - don't use it for anything else.
- You can use `gettid()` which is a Linux specific call that gets the process number associated with a thread under Linux. That's right, each thread under Linux has a 'hidden' PID, and `gettid()` returns it. This is the thread ID you can get `ps` to display. This is marginally less disgusting.

Ensure the calls you make are thread safe. `sprintf` is OK. `syslog` definitely is not threadsafe (and I've been bitten by that). You thus many need a mutex to protec this.

Comment: Worth noting is that `printf` is not re-entrant, meaning you cannot safely call this in an interrupt handler. See `man 7 signal` to find a list of safe functions to call. Though `write` is considerd a safe function, meaning you could write to `stdout` using that instead, if you're not already doing it.

Comment: I *think* he's calling it from threads, and not from signal handlers. `printf` is thread safe, as `stdio` is thread safe. But I've added a comment.